# How to use real emulator

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I am using lenovo k3 note smartphone and running android studio on Windows 7. I want my phone to run my app. I have enabled usb debugging option. But I couldn't find my device in emulator window.

In device manager of win7 when I am trying to install the driver it says:

> Windows was unable to install your MTP.
>   Windows couldn't find driver software for your device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: first check your usb driver, then install lenovo device driver

Comment: How to check usb driver? If you please clarify step by step that will be very helpful.

Comment: Use [Universal ADB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/). Pretty much easier to install device drivers.

Comment: Thanks @Shashanth, the driver works fine, but can you please tell me what was the problem? Previously when I connect my device it showed that the driver didn't installed correctly. Wasn't there an inbuilt driver in my phone?

Comment: To be honest I suggest this driver for all USB driver related problems. Because it's easy to install instead of searching for device specific drivers. May be you forgot [Connect as](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht104844) option in your phone. If you select this option you should be able to check CD drive option which contains built-in driver. Afterwards goto Windows Explorer and there you can see CD drive mounted. just install the driver from it. :)